# gridview databind

Tags: asp.net

I'm doing a gridview with an object datasource:

```
List<MyObject> TheSource = a linq query
```

At some point, I have

```
MyGridview.DataSource = TheSource;
MyGridview.Databind();
```

and an OnRowDataBound event handler that's tied to the databinding.

In that event handler, how do you make column 2 contain 2 objects from TheSource. For instance, in the TheSource, there is a variable for FirstName and another one for LastName. Column 2 needs to contain both the first and last name in the same cell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span>
            <%# Eval("FirstName").ToString() +' '+ Eval("LastName").ToString()%>
         </span>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```